# How to force Firefox to ask user for permission regarding IndexedDB usage of my app?

Tags: firefox, permissions, indexeddb

I made a prototype app [here](http://pfa-kadet.doweb.ro) which works on my machine (FF 13.0.1).
In order to do some more tests I tried to see how it behaves when user first time accesses it.
So I opened a virtual machine and run it.
The problem is that I do NOT receive any permision ask from the browser regarding local database usage for my app and because of this my app doesn't run as expected.
However, while I was looking for some explicit permision settings, firefox asked me id I want to give to my app access to local databases usage. After that, my app worked.

So, how can I force Firefox to ask user for permision regarding IndexedDB usage for my app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, you're asked permissions when IndexedDB installs for the first time on a host (origin, port and protocol matching), but this is apparently not the default behavior in Firefox.

According to [this helpful Mozilla support ticket](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/818987#answer-180011), [there seem to be two types of permissions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757678) in FF: "indexedDB" and "indexedDB-unlimited." Only the latter comes into play; the user doesn't have to grant permission until the 50mb ceiling is reached.

The ticket describes expected behavior as allowing IDB by default and not seeing a prompt:

> Expected - app should finish loading and allow indexed DB by default
>   without a prompt

If you'd like to control permissioning consistently in a cross browser way, I suggest you take matters in your own hand as the spec does not proffer a way that browsers should be going about this and we can see Chrome and Mozilla teams already disagree.

For example, store a "1" in `localStore` when the user grants permission and a "0" when she denies it. Refuse to open a database for someone with a "0" and prompt for permissions for those with an "undefined" as a flag.